# What are some Weather Widgets I can use?

Tags: dashboard-widget

I really need some Weather Widgets to use on Dashboard. Please give me your best widgets I can use.

Comment: Which version of OS X are you using? Editing your question to include that information may be useful.

Comment: As the site discourages "find me the best X" - would you take a stab at editing in your requirements for OS and why Apple's weather widget doesn't meet your needs? That way it won't be so open to all answers being equally valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Living earth](http://www.livingearthapp.com/) is quite cool. Don't know if it's a widget. Works on ipad, iphone and [mac](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/living-earth-desktop-weather/id539362919?mt=12).

[image]

> Enjoy a stunning live 3D simulation of our planet with global weather, forecasts and world clock for cities around the world. View live global cloud patterns, hurricanes and tropical storms. Explore and experience amazing weather dynamics on our planet with real-time 3D weather maps and typhoon and hurricane tracking. Living Earth is the best and most beautiful World Clock, Weather and Alarm available for your iPhone and iPad!